# Symbolic differentiation using boost proto

Tags: c++, boost-proto

I am trying to build an EDSL that can handle symbolic differentiation. I'm having trouble when it comes to function.

```
struct Derivative
: or_<
    when<
        terminal<unknown>
        , boost::mpl::int_<1>()
    >
    , when<
        terminal<_>
        , boost::mpl::int_<0>()
    >
    , proto::when<
        proto::function<proto::literal<function<1> >, Derivative>
        , proto::_make_function(proto::_left, Derivative(proto::_right))
    >
    , proto::when<
        proto::function<proto::literal<function<2> >, Derivative>
        , proto::_make_function(proto::_left, Derivative(proto::_right))
    >
    , otherwise<_>
> {};
```

In the last to parts of this struct, I capture functions separately because I want to be able to pass something other than `proto::_left` as the function to be applied.

Eg. `proto::literal<function<2> >` corresponds to the tanh function and my context will evaluate this as tanh. But when I see tanh in my expression that I want the derivative of, in my `Derivative` structure, I want to be able to say

```
proto::when<
  proto::function<proto::literal<function<2> >, Derivative>
  , proto::_make_function(proto::literal<function<7> >, Derivative(proto::_right))
>
```

`proto::literal<function<7> >` corresponds to gradient of tanh.

When I attempt to this this, my code does not compile.

How can I correctly do this?

Comment: I suppose you have already seen it, but Joel Falcou's [Getting jiggy with proto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3YCrqYPN4M) ([Exercises and solution](https://github.com/jfalcou/boost-con-2011/tree/master/proto)) may be useful.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jfalcou/boost-con-2011/blob/master/proto/step2/solution/step2-00.cpp#L30) is how the final solution is used. With that you can see if this solution suits your problem before you invest 3 hours in the video.